# How use data dynamically in LineChart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js, dashboard

I develop function for **LineChart** in my dashboard, if the data static the function work, but I use data dynamically!. How can use data dynamically in LineChart, I work with Angular 5 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
file.ts:

```
public lines: PieChartData[];
public lineChartData: Array<any> = [];
public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = [];
  public lineChartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true
  };
  public lineChartColors: Array<any> = [
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(143,108,99,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(143,108,99,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(143,108,99,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(143,108,99,0.8)'
    },
    { // dark grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(45,92,138,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(45,92,138,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(45,92,138,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(45,92,138,1)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }
  ];
  public lineChartLegend: boolean = true;
  public lineChartType: string = 'line';

constructor(private _ticketService: TicketService, private http: HttpClient,
    private _dashbordService: DashbordService, private _userService: UserService) { }

 async ngOnInit() {

    let id = localStorage.getItem('userId');
this.lines = await this._dashbordService.getLine(id, 1);
    for (var k = 0; k < this.lines.length; k++) {
      this.lineChartLabels.push(this.lines[k].x);
      this.lineChartData.push(this.lines[k].y);
    }
```

file.html:

```
<div class="ibox-body" *ngIf="lines">
          <div style="display: block;">
            <canvas baseChart height="120"
                    [datasets]="lineChartData" 
                    [labels]="lineChartLabels" 
                    [options]="lineChartOptions"
                    [colors]="lineChartColors"
                    [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                    [chartType]="lineChartType"
                    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ngIf waits for lines to be not null, but 'lines' already has a value when you fill your dataset. Your chart is being created before your dataset is ready. 
Try

```
<div class="ibox-body" *ngIf="lineChartData">
      <div style="display: block;">
        <canvas baseChart height="120"
                [datasets]="lineChartData" 
                [labels]="lineChartLabels" 
                [options]="lineChartOptions"
                [colors]="lineChartColors"
                [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                [chartType]="lineChartType"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If this doesn't work, can you post your services' function you use to get data?